# Phrase which means to "code in" a programming language

Tags: word-choice, verbs, phrase-request

What do you **do** with a *programming* language?

1. > I know C++, but it's been years since I last **worked with** it.
2. > I know C++, but it's been years since I last **worked on** it.

Of course, we could always use the seemingly more obvious (and safer) alternative:

3. > It's been years since I last **coded in** C++.

but that's not what I want.

**Is there any word/phrase which means to "code in" a programming language?**

Comment: Why don't you want *to code in*?  But you could always say just *to write*.

Comment: Remember that you're not *working on* C++ unless you are developing the language itself.

Comment: You could use "developed in it" or "programmed in/with it", but that's not really significantly different than "coded in".  Honestly if I were just to say something like this, I'd probably just went with "I know C++ but it's been years since I've used it."

Comment: @PMV Doesn't saying that I "use" a programming language brand the language as a mere object to use rather than a language to code in?

Comment: Not if you're a developer. I say "use" all the time with coworkers and everyone knows what I mean.

Comment: Couldn't you post it as an answer? Have people got too lazy these days?

Comment: It's "use" more in the sense that one uses knowledge - for example, "I learned calculus but haven't used it in decades".  There's not a negative connotation to the word "use" in this sense, it's not somehow trivializing the knowledge of calculus or programming.

Comment: I'm a programmer in Delphi and later in PHP and Java and I have never heard the verb "work" used with a programming language. It just sounds odd. The options I know are develop, write in , code in, and even use.

Comment: My husband is a software engineer and he says he "codes", or he is "coding", if he mentions the language, he might say, "I'm coding in/using C++."

Comment: @M K: "Have you ever **worked with** C?" is a perfectly legitimate and not uncommon way of phrasing the question. **used**, **coded in**, **programmed in**, are all OK variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A commonly used verb is **to program**.

> Do you know how to **program** in Lisp?

P.S. This would be quite facetious:

Perl spoken here.

Comment: the obvious choice